# Image shrinks when put inside customtkinter button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I have an image of the size around (900x850), even bigger than my application's window which is (800x600), but when I put it inside a button of the size (200x200) it shrinks so much as shown in the picture below.
[Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eks0p.png)

This is how I open the image:
`addUserIcon = customtk.CTkImage(Image.open("addUserIcon.png"))`
This is my Button code:

```
addUserAccountButton = customtk.CTkButton(adminDashboardLabel, image=addUserIcon, 
width=150, height=150, text="", corner_radius=20, fg_color="#5E7BE3", hover_color="#4461C7")

addUserAccountButton.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.4, anchor = "center")
```

Comment: You need to specify the size of the image when creating instance of `CTkImage`, otherwise it is 20x20 by default.

Comment: How can I do that please? I am a newbie :)
EDIT: I found out how, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was changing this:

```
addUserIcon = customtk.CTkImage(Image.open("addUserIcon.png"))
```

To this:

```
addUserIcon = customtk.CTkImage(Image.open("addUserIcon.png"), size=(40, 40))
```

By using the attribute:

```
size=(x, y)
```